# Adding weight to each set?

Tags: weightlifting, bodybuilding, muscle-mass, hypertrophy

Should I add weight to each set if im aiming for hypertrophy? (Pyramid sets or straight sets, etc?)

Comment: related to pyramid sets https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/28445/does-loading-and-unloading-weight-help-build-muscle-lose-fat-and-develop-streng/28451#28451 and https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24280/pyramid-training-high-to-low-or-low-to-high